# Reading csv ,saving in dataframe, putting if condition, not getting exectped result

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm reading csv, saving it into dataframe and using if condition but I'm not getting expected result.

My python code below :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import operator
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.now ( ).strftime ( '%m/%d/%Y' )
stockRules = pd.read_csv("C:\stock_rules.csv", dtype={"Product Currently Out of Stock": str}).drop_duplicates(subset="Product Currently Out of Stock", keep="last" )

pd.to_datetime(stockRules['FROMMONTH'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
pd.to_datetime(stockRules['TOMONTH'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

 if stockRules['FROMMONTH'] <= dt and stockRules['TOMONTH'] >= dt:
        print(stockRules)
```

My csv file is below :

```
Productno   FROMMONTH   TOMONTH
120041      2/1/2019    5/30/2019
112940      2/1/2019    5/30/2019
121700      2/1/2019    2/1/2019
```

I want to read csv file and want to print the product number, which meets the condition only.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide a sample of your data `stock_rules.csv`.

Comment: added above named as csv file

Comment: What are you getting instead? `IndentationError`? `KeyError`?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the code a bit and simplified it somewhat, but the idea behind the selection should still work the same:

```
dt = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
stockRules = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=";")

stockRules["FROMMONTH"] = pd.to_datetime(stockRules["FROMMONTH"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
stockRules["TOMONTH"] = pd.to_datetime(stockRules["TOMONTH"], format="%m/%d/%Y")

sub = stockRules[(stockRules["FROMMONTH"] <= dt) & (dt <= stockRules["TOMONTH"])]
print(sub["Productno"])
```

Notice that when using `pd.to_datetime` I am assigning the result of the operation to the original column, overriding whatever was in it before.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** 
For my tests I changed the CSV to use ; as delimiter, since I had trouble reading in the data you provided in your question. Might be that you will have to specify another delimiter. For tabs for example:

```
stockRules = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter="\t")
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'FROMMONTH'

Comment: The CSV in your question uses a couple of empty spaces to separate entries. Are you sure your original file is properly strucutred? Because it sounds to me like pandas cannot proplery process it. I suggest trying my code with a CSV containing test data separated by a ; character.